# RabbitMQ - Exchange/Queues dissapearing

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am using the Bunny implementation of RabbitMQ messaging

I have a bash script that provisions a durable topic exchange, a number of durable queues and binds them.
I am using Bunny on both client and server side to send messages between them.

However, I find that on terminating either connection (client/server) that my exchange and queues dissapear. I would like to configure it so that even if the server side fails, the client can still push messages to the queue and they will be processed once the server is back online.

Is this possible  with Bunny/RabbitMQ?

Comment: See tutorial http://rubybunny.info/articles/queues.html.

Comment: "Durable queues that are shared by many consumers and have an independent existence: i.e. they will continue to exist and collect messages whether or not there are consumers to receive them." It seems for me that this is not true if a connection to the server is closed?

Comment: "shared message queues that are deleted when the last of many consumers disconnects." - How do I avoid this behaviour?